# Syntax highlighting in octopress

Tags: syntax, octopress

What do I need to do to make syntax highlighting work on octopress? Here's what I currently have:

````
``` ruby 
 class Fixnum
   def prime?
     ('1' * self) !~ /^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/
   end
 end
```
````

There's no whitespace on the left side of the backtick and I place a single whitespace between the leftmost part of the editor and the code which I want to be highlighted.

I also tried codeblocks but no luck even if I already copy pasted the example on their site:

```
{% codeblock lang:objc %}
[rectangle setX: 10 y: 10 width: 20 height: 20];
{% endcodeblock %}
```

Is there anything else that I need to install? I believe codeblocks and backticks are already included when I installed octopress. But it still looks like this even if I include the language:

[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: I have this working with latest octopress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you solved your issue?

If not, you can try using **different markdown engines** (default is rdiscount + pygments).

Other possible engines are kramdown, redcarpet and maruku, which **use ruby instead of python**, so if you have issues with python this might solve them.

I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.alestanis.com/2013/02/04/octopress-and-the-twilight-color-scheme/) about how to set up kramdown with Octopress, you can check it out.

Answer (score 2):

- A Sass port of [Solarized syntax highlighting](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) created specifically for Octopress.
- Gist code embedding - by [Brandon Tilly](https://gist.github.com/1027674).
- Insert code snippets from your filesystem with a download link.
- Easy inline code blocks with `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` and optional download links.
- Pygments caching - a [Jekyll community plugin](https://github.com/rsim/blog.rayapps.com/blob/master/_plugins/pygments_cache_patch.rb).
- Table based line numbers added with javascript.

[Octopress Sharing Code Snippets](http://octopress.org/docs/blogging/code/)

Comment: yeah I followed those but no luck. As you can see I've even copy pasted the examples on the octopress docs but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which is you using? Show me the post or link. :)

Comment: its already in my question. I'm using the back ticks. I also specified the language which is ruby but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Can you make sure you have a python package installed? `python2.7` is work fine. [More info](https://github.com/tmm1/pygments.rb/issues/10)

Comment: I got this error: Liquid error: undefined method `Py_IsInitialized’ for RubyPython::Python:Module what do I need to do?

Comment: 1.Try this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/. It is python extensions package for windows.2.Try to modify 
path/to/rubypython/rubypython/pythonexec.rb like [this issue](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/262).3.[other issue](https://github.com/github/gollum/issues/225)